# Finding the number of times a line will intersect with other lines on the plot

Tags: matplotlib

Using

```
plt.plot(x[i:i+2], y[i:i+2], 'ro-')
```

to create some line segments:
[image]

If one plots x = 0.6, is there a matplotlib built in method of finding the number of times it will intersect with lines that have already been plotted on the graph?

Comment: Why not do it directly on the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given segment where you know x[2i] and x[2i+1], you have an intersection if your given x falls in between. The best way to check is to compute `(x-x[2*i])*(x-x[2*i+1])`. If less than zero, you have an intersection. If equal to zero, one of the end points is on your x=0.6 line. If greater than zero it means that the ends of the segment are on the same side of the line, so no intersection.
To program this, assuming that x is a numpy array
`prod=(0.6-x[::2])*(0.6-x[1::2])`
And the number of intersections is `len(numpy.where(prod>=0)[0])`